# jQuery move contents of one div into another append() not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am working on a tabbed layout using Bootstrap 2.3.2 in Joomla and due to the way Hikashop generates a product layout, I have an outer "tab-content" div and when putting in a product description, the result is an inner "tab-content div within a "tab-pane" with a single nav at the top of the page. I am attempting to move the inner "tab-pane"s to the outer "tab-content" via jQuery using append() so that the nav will function correctly. Needless to say this is not working. The nav is not functioning period, and the content that has been appended is getting duplicated.

**here is what my code looks like:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#home" data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="outer" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <div id="inner" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#inner").append("#outer");
    });
</script>
```

**and here is the desired outcome:**

```
<div id="outer" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `appendTo`:

```
jQuery("#inner").children().appendTo("#outer");
```

Comment: jQuery("#inner .tab-pane").appendTo("#outer"); that worked, thanks! whats the functional difference between append and appendTo?

Comment: I edited my answer. Take a look.
About your question: "The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container." http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery("#inner").appendTo('#outer');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      --start inside #home --
        <div id="inner" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">#profile</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">#messages</div>
        </div>
      --end inside #home --
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">--inside #settings --</div>
  -- outside tab-pane --
</div>
```